# How can I put the result of the data in variable to the other variable?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a = "time(0)";
$b = eval($a);
```

Like this, I want to put the result of the data....

I can put the string with eval code.. But how can I do this?

Comment: why would you ever want to? just looks lie a real bad idea

Comment: Dagon / I want to put data for many kinds... I can use switch statement but I don't think it is a good idea.. like that (in for statement) -> $foo[$i] = $bar["health"][$i];

Comment: no eval is a bad idea. jsut dont

Comment: in $bar["health"=>["1","time(0)", "rawurlencode($tmp)", "$obj->ttt($tmp)"]

Comment: @Dagon explain why no? its not valid to say "NO".

Comment: um... then What is the best way to implement?

Comment: based on your code, i have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: how does `time(0)` get in to the string in the first place, why not add the value (of `time(0)`) to the string instead of the function name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) your string must contain completed php code, ie has `;` at the end

2) code in the string doesn't produce any output and it results in NULL value of $b

So, to make it working, write:

```
$a = "time(0)";
$b = eval("echo ".$a.";");
echo $b; // 1433582861
```

Comment: What a reason for down voting?

Comment: absolutely no reason to use eval, and its is considered a terrible and dangerous practice

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you,

```
$a = "time(0)";
$b = call_user_func($a);
$c = new DateTime($b);
var_dump($c);
```